# How to compute a specific vector given a set of inequalities?

Tags: geometry

I need a (more or less consistent) way of computing a vector in Mathematica given a set of inequalities that define non-empty convex polytope. Because the question has a strong applied background (Game Theory), let me describe my problem intuitively by means of a simple example.

First, the **preliminaries**. Consider a function $v:2^N\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $N=\{1,2,3\}$ and $2^N$ denotes the Power Set of $N$. Then, consider the following set of inequalities: $
x_i \geqslant v(\{i\}) \forall i\in N$; $x_1+x_2+x_3=v(\{1,2,3\})$; $x_1+x_2\geqslant v(\{1,2\})$; $x_1+x_3\geqslant v(\{1,3\})$ and $x_2+x_3\geqslant v(\{2,3\})$. Let us suppose that the set of vectors $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ that solve the previous set of inequalities is non-empty. If so, this set is known to be a convex polytope whose vertices can be derived from the previous set of inequalities.

To see so, consider now the following **example**: $v(\{1,2,3\})=1$, $v(\{1,2\})=0.75$, $v(\{1,3\})=0.50$, $v(\{2,3\})=0.25$ and $v(\{i\})=0\forall i \in \{1,2,3\}$. The following code solves for the corresponding set of inequalities, thus providing the set of vertices of the polytope given by $v$.

```
Reduce[{x + y + z == 1, x + y >= 0.75, x + z >= 0.5, y + z >= 0.25, x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0}, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

From there, it can be readily verified that the vertices of my polytope (a polygon, in this particular case) are given by $(0.75,0.25,0),(0.75,0,0.25), (0.25,0.50,0.25)\text{ and }(0.50,0.50,0)$.

**Now, the problem**. Consider all orders over the set $N$. Now, consider the lexicographic maximum of each of these $|N|!$ orders with respect to the set of vertices. Let $\pi_i\in\Pi$ denote each order and $\lambda_{\pi_{i}}$ denote the lexicographic maximum for each order $\pi_i$. In other words, in our particular example: (i) for order $\pi_1=\{1,2,3\}$, $\lambda_{\pi_{1}}=(0.75,0.25,0)$; (ii) for orders $\pi_2=\{1,3,2\}$ and $\pi_6=\{3,1,2\}$, $\lambda_{\pi_{2}}=\lambda_{\pi_{6}}=(0.75,0,0.25)$; (iii) for order $\pi_3=\{2,1,3\}$, $\lambda_{\pi_{3}}=(0.50,0.50,0)$ and (iv) for orders $\pi_4=\{2,3,1\}$ and $\pi_5=\{3,2,1\}$, $\lambda_{\pi_{4}}=\lambda_{\pi_{5}}=(0,25,0.50,0.25)$.

Averaging all lexicographic maximums over all possible orders, we get $
\mathfrak{A}=\frac{1}{|N|!}\cdot\sum_{\pi_{i}\in\Pi} \lambda_{\pi_{i}}$. In our case, $\mathfrak{A}=\left(\frac{13}{24},\frac{7}{24},\frac{4}{24}\right)$. Then, I have **two questions**:

1. Can anyone provide code in Mathematica that computes this vector $\mathfrak{A}$ for my particular example?
2. Can anyone provide code in Mathematica that computes this vector $\mathfrak{A}$ given a set $N$ such that $|N|=4$ and a generic function $v:N\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Thank you all very much in advance for your time.

Comment: If $\nu$ is affine-linear then `LinearProgramming` might help you (see also this [introductory site](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLinearProgramming.html). It finds the minimum or (maximum) of a linear function restricted to a convex polytope, defined by affine-linear equalities. Using an arbitrary linear function, you can employ it to find feasible points, i.e., points within this polytope.

Comment: Have also a look at the option `Method -> "InteriorPoint"`. This should speed up things considerably.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'm a total noob in Mathematica and I was not aware of such a resource. I'll dig into it later to see if I can get what I need from there.

Comment: You're welcome! Let me know if you need further advice (write a comment that includes @HenrikSchumacher to ping me).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: I've spent these two hours trying stuff and reading in the introductory site and I certainly don't see how "LinearProgramming" could help me. Could you please provide any further hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the defining inequalities then the idea is the same regardless of dimension. Take all orders, find successive maxima for a given order, then average. The code below has some redundancy, so is not as efficient as it might be.

```
opt[order_, constraints_, vars_] := Module[
  {cons = constraints, max, vals, var},
  Do[var = vars[[order[[j]]]]; {max, vals} = 
    Maximize[{var, cons}, vars]; 
   cons = Join[cons, {var == (var /. vals)}];
   , {j, Length[vars]}];
  vars /. vals
  ]
```

The example:

```
vars = Array[x, 3];
constraints = {x + y + z == 1, x + y >= 0.75, x + z >= 0.5, 
    y + z >= 0.25, x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0} /. 
   Thread[{x, y, z} -> vars];
orders = Permutations[Range[3]];

Mean[Table[opt[order, constraints, vars], {order, orders}]]

(* Out[654]= {0.541666666667, 0.291666666667, 0.166666666667} *)
```

Comment: I have computed manually the vector I should get for a couple of examples with $|N|=4$ and your code delivers the desired vector. Hence, I have accepted your answer. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 4):

You may use `LinearProgramming` in order to find a point within a convex polytope defined by affine-linear equalities and inequalities. To this end, the conditions have to be encoded into a matrix `m` and a vector `b` such that the conditions are equivalent to `m.vars >= b` and `var>=0`; both inequalities are meant elementwise. This is often called *standard form* (beware that different authors use different conventions) and how every linear program can be transformed into standard form can be found, e.g., [here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~burke/crs/407/lectures/L4-lp_standard_form.pdf).

The following code will perform that for you; we start with your example problem:

```
cond = {x + y + z == 1, x + y >= 0.75, x + z >= 0.5, y + z >= 0.25, 
   x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0};
vars = {x, y, z};
```

The following transforms these conditions into standard form:

```
cond1 = cond /. {
Equal[a_, b_] :> Equal[a - b, 0],
LessEqual[a_, b_] :> GreaterEqual[b - a, 0],
GreaterEqual[a_, b_] :> GreaterEqual[a - b, 0]
};
eq = Cases[cond1, _Equal];
ineq = Cases[cond1, _GreaterEqual];
c = ConstantArray[0., 2 Length[vars]];
With[{ToPack = Developer`ToPackedArray},
  Aeq = ToPack@N@D[eq[[All, 1]], {vars, 1}];
  beq = ToPack@N@(Aeq.vars - eq[[All, 1]]);
  Aineq = ToPack@N@D[ineq[[All, 1]], {vars, 1}];
  bineq = ToPack@N@(N@Aineq.vars - ineq[[All, 1]]);
  ];
m = ArrayFlatten[{
    {Aeq, -Aeq},
    {-Aeq, Aeq},
    {Aineq, -Aineq}
    }];
b = Join[beq, -beq, bineq];
```

Now we are ready to fead it to `LinearProgramming`; it will look for a minimizer of the linear function `Dot[c,vars]` on the described polytope. Hence (`c` being the zero vector), it will just return any point in the polytope. With standard options, this will be always a corner of the polytope.

```
sol = With[{sol0 = LinearProgramming[c, m, b]},
 sol0[[1 ;; Length[vars]]] - sol0[[Length[vars] + 1 ;; 2 Length[vars]]]
 ]
```

> {0.75, 0., 0.25}

Checking if the solution is feasible:

```
Show[
 DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[cond, Evaluate@vars],
 Graphics3D[Sphere[sol, 0.01]]
 ]
```

[image]

Aha, seems to be okay.

The number of variables and conditions is quite irrelevant; `LinearProgramming` is built for medium to large scale application.

**Edit**

If you need all corners of the polytope then the following should work: The idea is that every corner has to satisfy all linear equality and a suitable number if (linear independent) inequalities is active. A brute force method 
might be

```
p = DeleteDuplicates@Quiet@DeleteCases[
     Table[
      LinearSolve[Join[Aeq, Aineq[[idx]]], Join[beq, bineq[[idx]]]],
      {idx, 
       Subsets[Range[Length[Aineq]], {Length[vars] - Length[Aeq]}]}],
     _LinearSolve];
pts = Pick[p,
   Total[
    Subtract[1, 
     UnitStep[
      Subtract[Transpose[Aineq.Transpose[p]], 
       ConstantArray[bineq, Length[p]]]]],
    {2}
    ],
   0
   ];
```

Here, `p` is a list of all points that have suitably many active inequalities and from these, we sieve out the feasible ones (this is the list `pts`). Quick check:

```
Show[
 DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[cond, Evaluate@vars],
 Graphics3D[Sphere[pts, 0.01]]
 ]
```

[image]

**Further edit**

I think the following would solve your entire problem. At least for `nn=3` and `ν` as given above, it returns your result. However for `nn=4`, I was not able to find a function `ν` that does not produce empty polytopes; but that's certainly something you can fix yourself.

```
nn = 4;
bigN = Range[nn];
vars = Array[x, nn];
powerset = Subsets[bigN, {1, nn}];
ν = AssociationThread[powerset,RandomReal[{0,1},Length[powerset]]];
(* ν = AssociationThread[powerset, {0., 0., 0., 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 1.}]; *)
cond = Append[
   Table[Total[vars[[subset]]] >= ν[subset], {subset, 
     Most@powerset}],
   Total[vars] == ν[bigN]
   ];

cond1 = cond /. {
    Equal[a_, b_] :> Equal[a - b, 0],
    LessEqual[a_, b_] :> GreaterEqual[b - a, 0],
    GreaterEqual[a_, b_] :> GreaterEqual[a - b, 0]
    };
eq = Cases[cond1, _Equal];
ineq = Cases[cond1, _GreaterEqual];
With[{ToPack = Developer`ToPackedArray},
  Aeq = ToPack@N@D[eq[[All, 1]], {vars, 1}];
  beq = ToPack@N@(Aeq.vars - eq[[All, 1]]);
  Aineq = ToPack@N@D[ineq[[All, 1]], {vars, 1}];
  bineq = ToPack@N@(N@Aineq.vars - ineq[[All, 1]]);
  ];

p = DeleteDuplicates@
   Quiet@DeleteCases[
     Table[LinearSolve[Join[Aeq, Aineq[[idx]]], 
       Join[beq, bineq[[idx]]]], {idx, 
       Subsets[Range[
         Length[Aineq]], {Length[vars] - 
          Length[Aeq]}]}], _LinearSolve];
pts = Pick[p, 
   Total[Subtract[1, 
     UnitStep[
      Subtract[Transpose[Aineq.Transpose[p]], 
       ConstantArray[bineq, Length[p]]]]], {2}], 0];

If[Length[pts] == 0,
 0,
 1/nn! Sum[
   pts[[Ordering[pts[[All, π]], -1][[1]]]], {π, 
    Permutations[Range[nn]]}]
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your Edit. Seeing your extended answer, let me be more specific. I do not need all vertices of the polytope. Instead, I need all the vertices that are lexicographically maximum for at least one order. Your original answer finds one of these lexicographical maximum vertices; the extended answer solves the Vertex Enumeration Problem. What I need is is right in between. Is my problem better explained now? I am sorry for any misunderstanding my previous comment may have generated.

Comment: I was doing something wrong: your code compiles perfectly. Having said that, my previous comment still holds. Notice that in the particular example I provide, all vertices are lexicographically maximum for at least one order, but this does not need to be the case for a general convex polytope. Thank you very much again.

Comment: @Héctor, there _was_ an error in the code, but I fixed it in the meantime.

Comment: Forget my last comment. I never saw that there was a commented line. Call me stupid. Answer accepted. I'll play now with nn=4. Thank you a lot for the time you spent on this.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @HenrikSchaumacher: is it possible to get the same but with rational numbers instead of reals? Where in the code can I specify the domain? I know I can rationalize the result, but this is not very professional, to be honest.

Comment: Sure. `RandomReal` in  produces a list of ... erm... random reals. Replace that with a list of your choice. Then either remove all occurences of `N@` or apply `Rationalize` to the final result.

Comment: @HenrikSchaumacher: the line \[Nu] = AssociationThread[
   powerset, {0., 0., 0., 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 3.}]; which introduces the Game into the code, in which order does so? In this case, it clearly is \[Nu] = AssociationThread[
   powerset, {x, y, z, x+y, x+z, y+z, x+y+z}]; but how to extend it to N=4? Is it like \[Nu] = AssociationThread[
   powerset, {x, y, z, a, x+y, x+z, x+a, y+z, y+a, z+a, x+y+z, x+y+a, x+z+a, y+z+a, x+y+z+a}];?

Comment: You just have to repace `RandomReal[{0,1},Length[powerset]]` by a list of numbers of the same length (the length is `Length[powerset]`). `nn=4` tells the system that you want dimension 4.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and all your effort. However, after seeing Daniel Lichtblau's answer, I'm afraid I need to accept his answer. This is so because his code correctly computes the desired vector some examples with $|N|=4$, whereas yours is close, but does not deliver what it should.

Comment: [Sorry about that...] Having forgotten to upvote this a few days ago, I did manage to partly reset the cosmic balance of things.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau It's okay, your answer is more concise than mine. =)